# Is it possible to manually destroy SurfaceView?

Tags: android, surfaceview

My SurfaceView is not getting destroyed even if onPause of the activity is called.

I am taking care of the thread in

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (mGameThread.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
        createGameThread(getHolder(), getContext());
    }
    mGameThread.setRunning(true);
    mGameThread.start();
}


public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    mGameThread.setRunning(false);
    while (retry) {
        try {
            mGameThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

As an hack I have to check the state of the thread in onResume and if the thread is already  terminated, I would finish the activity

```
protected void onResume() {
    Log.d(mLogTag, "onResume()");
    super.onResume();
    if (mGameThread != null) {
        if (mGameThread.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
            finish();
        }
    }

}
```

Unfortunately it is not possible to move the thread handling from surfaceDestroyed and surfaceCreated to onPause() and onResume() of the activity. Is it possible to manually destroy the SurfaceView in the onPause() and recreate it in onResume()?

Answer (score 4):

You can add surface view  dynamically on your view.

Example :layout.xml

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_file_videoplayer_surface_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
FrameLayout fl_surfaceview_container = 
              (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.fragment_file_videoplayer_surface_container);

// Add surfaceView on Framelayout

SurfaceView videoSurface = new SurfaceView(getActivity());
fl_surfaceview_container.addView(videoSurface);

//if remove or destroy surfaceview

fl_surfaceview_container.removeAllViews();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a layout as a parent of the surfaceview, then set visibility of the layout GONE in onPause(), and set VISIBLE in onResume() of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible.
First initialize Size

```
   Size currentSurfaceSize;

   cameraSurface.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(QR_Reader_Activity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, RequestCameraPermission);
                        permission = true;
                        return;
                    }
                    try {
                        cameraSource.start(cameraSurface.getHolder());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        currentSurfaceSize = new Size(width, height);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    onPause();
                }
            });
```

where do you want to destroy the surface, use this below code.

```
              if (currentSurfaceSize==null){
                    cameraSurface = (SurfaceView) cameraSurface.getHolder();
                    cameraSurface.removeCallbacks((Runnable) cameraSurface);
              }
```