# SurfaceView for Camera Preview won't get destroyed when pressing Power-Button

Tags: java, android, android-camera, surfaceview, activity-lifecycle

I want to implement a camera preview. For that I have a custom View `CameraView extends ViewGroup` that in the constructor programmatically creates an surfaceView.

I have the following components (higly simplified for beverity):

ScannerFragment.java

```
public View onCreateView(..) {
   //inflate view and get cameraView
}

public void onResume() {
   //open camera -> set rotation -> startPreview (in a thread) -> 
   //set preview callback -> start decoding worker
}

public void onPause() {
   // stop decoding worker -> stop Preview -> release camera
}
```

CameraView.java extends ViewGroup

```
public void setUpCalledInConstructor(Context context) {
   //create a surfaceview and add it to this viewgroup ->
   //get SurfaceHolder and set callback
}

/* SurfaceHolder.Callback */
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
   camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    //NOTHING is done here
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    camera.getParameters().setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
}
```

fragment_scanner.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.myapp.camera.CameraView
        android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I think I have set the lifecycle correct (getting resources onResume(), releasing it onPause() roughly said) and the following works just fine:

- pressing home and returning
- pressing Taskswitcher and returning
- rotation
- pressing back (of course)

But one thing doesn't work and that is when I press the power-button on the device and then return to the camera-preview. The result is: the preview is stuck with the image that was last captured before button was pressed. If I rotate it works fine again, since it will get through the lifecycle.

[After some research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971811/android-difference-between-pressing-home-button-and-power-button) I found out that this is probably due to the fact that surfaceView won't get destroyed when the power-button is pressed, i.e. `SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)` won't be called. And in fact when I compare the (very verbose) log output of the home-button-case and the power-button-case it's the same except that 'surfaceDestroyed' won't get called.

So far I found no solution whatsoever to work around it. I purposely avoid any resource cleaning code in my `surfaceDestroyed()`, but this does not help. My idea was to [manually destroy the surfaceView like asked in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134604/is-it-possible-to-manually-destroy-surfaceview) but this seems not possible. I also tested other applications with surfaceViews/cameras and they don't seem to have this issue. So I would appreciate any hints or tips on that.

Comment: To recap: The problem was a bug in the lifecycle of the app. Basically some onCreate/onResume missed some setup required in specfic cases.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to add

```
 public void onDestroy() {
 // stop decoding worker -> stop Preview -> release camera
}
```

as done for the onPause() cause it might be invoked as long as the pause method.

In my releaseCamera() that's what i do

```
    private void releaseCamera() {
    if (myCamera != null) {
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
        preview.removeView(myPreview);
        myCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        myCamera.release();
        myCamera = null;

    }
}
```

I detach the CameraPreview (myPreview), that is what holds the current picture. And fully destroy the camera.

Comment: The problem is not that my stop/destroy code isn't invoked, but that I have no option whatsoever to manually destroy the surfaceview because it should destroy itself

Answer (score 0):

mPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mPreview); should help?